# How to use zvs driver to power tesla coil's primary

Tags: tesla-coil

So, i am thinking about making my own crude tesla coil which would work upto 30volts. I got a zvs driver for that purpose. The zvs driver has 3 output lines( 1 positive and other 2 ground). Most of the tesla projects i see have no center tap on the primary of tesla coil. So would it be okay to use a cenre tapped primary for tesla coil? If not what is the possible solution for it?[image]
 Note that zvs driver is basically an oscillator circuit which generates high frequencies necessary for mutual induction.

Comment: What is a "zvs driver?" Define acronyms in text on first usage.  It makes life easier for people reading your text.

Comment: Go for it. We don't normally centre-tap a Tesla primary. Might be a good idea to tightly couple the two halves, perhaps with a bifilar winding.

Comment: @JRE ZVS = Zero Voltage Switching. It's a popular driver scheme for flyback transformers, especially.

Comment: Huh? What's a "zvs driver"?  And why wouldn't it be "ZVS"?  Don't use undefined TLAs.  Closing as *unclear*.

Comment: @OlinLathrop For users familiar with high voltage projects "ZVS" is a well-known acronym for this driver type. I'm not saying the OP shouldn't have defined it, but I don't see a reason to penalize him for not doing it the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to use a center-tapped primary for a Tesla coil. Just tie the two grounds on the ZVS driver together and you have your high voltage supply between the yellow wire and the two tied grounds. Connect a high voltage rectifier diode to one leg of the output of the transformer, and put your spark gap between the diode and the black wire(s), and then put your capacitor and primary coil in series across the spark gap. That's how you would wire a ZVS driver to a Tesla coil. You may also want to add some high-frequency chokes as shown in the schematic below.

**UPDATED EDIT:**
I just realized that this device is *ONLY* the ZVS driver. It does not have a built-in high voltage transformer. You need to connect a flyback transformer of your own (See Image 1). The two outer connections are the switched connections, and the center wire (yellow) is the *common*, but in this case that does not mean *ground*. It does actually connect to the inductor (see Image 2).

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: I actually think that yellow wire is indeed positive because i have checked pcb connection and the yellow one goes to the inductor and other end of inductor to positive of power pin. And i think the current flows periodically from yellow to one of the black and then to the other black wire which creates oscillations.

Comment: @user133933 Please see the "Updated Edit". You are correct in that the center pin connects to the inductor, but you are incorrect in thinking the outer two connections are ground.

Comment: Oh i see... so is there any other way i can use this driver as tesla coil driver circuit? Or is this one made for flyback transformers only?i have tried induction heating with this module as well and it kinda works at 24v 2A although not so good but main purpose to buy this was to use it as tesla coil driver.

Comment: In order for the Tesla coil to work it needs a high voltage power supply. This driver will drive the high voltage power supply, but will not run the Tesla coil directly. If you want to build a solid state Tesla coil, that's a whole different project and I don't believe it can be done just with this driver.

Comment: There are couple of projects I came across while searching for this, ZVS driver drive the flyback (rectified or connect a HV-diode) then you can have a capacitor in series/parallel with the primary winding. Indeed the capacitor should be in HV values

Answer (score 1):

get a flyback transformer and power the transformer with your zvs circuit. then connect your two transformer H.V output wires to the spark gap of your tesla coil. should be good to go. Assuming you have correct capacitance.